# p2p via socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip-address, p2p

There are 2 android phones,
They want to communicate directly with P2P via socket connection.
Both phones know each other's IP address'
Both phones are behind different symmetric NATs
You have root access to both phones.
You are allowed to install additional software on the phones
No TURN server should be used in the communication path

how to achieve above scenario

Comment: These phones are connected via mobile internet?

Comment: `Both phones know each other's IP address'.  Not needed. If in same LAN only the client needs to know that. If in different LANs the client should know public ip of the router of the server device. If the Android server device uses mobile connection then installing a server makes no sense.

Comment: How do they learn each other's IP address?

Comment: They do not have to know each others ip address as you can read in my comment. Please ask to the point.